# Google IMA SDK client - How to Translate "Skip Ad" and "This ad will close in 5 seconds"

Tags: javascript, sdk, video-ads

I have pre-roll video ads on my site, I'm using Google IMA SDK client.

How can I translate "Skip" and "This ad will close in 5 seconds"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a language in the API using the [`language`](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/ios/v3/api/interface_i_m_a_settings#a02ace5be361a1c09375144d749640cae) parameter:

> **Language specification used for localization.**
>   |Language| must be formated as a canonicalized IETF BCP 47 language identifier such as would be returned by [NSLocale preferredLanguages]. Setting this property after it has been sent to the IMAAdsLoader will be ignored and a warning will be logged.